# relationship between nominal voltage and cross-sectional area

Tags: voltage, transmission-line

Is there a reasonable approximation or some standard cross-sectional area that can be inferred from the nominal voltage of a transmission line? I'm only concerned with high-voltage lines, i.e. nothing at the distribution level.  I don't need something exact and even a relative measure of how the cross-sectional area will likely change between a 69kV and 118kV line, for example, would be good. I'm happy to assume the same material for all lines and any other simplifying assumptions that would lead to something reasonable.

Comment: I think the cross-sectional area of the wires will be determined primarily by the current they are required to carry, rather than by the voltage.  For insulated wires, the voltage will determine the required insultation thickness, but I wouldn't expect HV distribution lines to be insulated.

Comment: Voltage has little to do with conductor cross sectional area- as Peter says- current and mechanical strength are likely the important factors- so the conductors may have  a steel core to provide the tensile strength. Skin effect also will be a factor, even at 50/60Hz (but not for DC transmission lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power distributors plan their lines for maximum profit. They can allow more losses if that keeps the lifetime cost smaller and the voltage variation norms still can be fulfilled. The cost estimation is stochastic - it takes the probablity of accidents and storms into the account, too.

If you have noticed some dependence between voltage and cross-sectional area, it is the result of forementioned  for lifetime calculations, not only because the current is different at different voltage levels.